# What is the correct capitalisation of the word "sonar"?

Tags: capitalization

What is the correct capitalisation of the word "sonar" (and why)?

Answer (score 9):

> SONAR

**SONAR** was originally an acronym for "**SO** und **N** avigation **A** nd **R** anging", although in common usage **sonar** is acceptable, with **Sonar** appearing at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: I sometimes despair of these *"What is the correct way..."* questions. It wouldn't be so bad if they just asked *"How do competent speakers/writers normally..."* But of course **you** are completely "correct". By way of proof (if such were needed) [here's what they actually write](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sonar%2CSonar%2CSONAR&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Bearing in mind that the (already relatively low) usages of *Sonar* are artificially inflated by many occasions when it starts a sentence, *sonar* is the out-and-out winner!

Comment: Isn't _sonar_ acceptable in 'non-common' usage? The dictionaries I've checked in don't indicate this.

Comment: My answer does say that :-)

Comment: I mean 'SONAR' is unusual to dubious in all registers nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

The Chicago Manual of Style notes (emphasis mine):

> Initialisms tend to appear in all capital letters, even when they are
>   not derived from proper nouns (HIV, VP, LCD). *With frequent use,
>   however, acronyms—especially those of five or more letters—will
>   sometimes become lowercase (scuba); those that are derived from proper
>   nouns retain an initial capital.*

"[A Brief History of Active Sonar](http://csi.whoi.edu/sites/default/files/literature/Full%20Text.pdf)" (note the capitalization of *sonar* in title case; the same applies at the start of a sentence) documents that *sonar* was coined in 1942, following the pattern of *radar*.

It's instructive to note that the forerunner of the sonar was the ultrasonic ASDIC (Allied Submarine Detection Investigation Committee); *asdic* is listed as a synonym for sonar in British English.

Answer (score 3):

Sonar has long been accepted as an ordinary word (since around 1979). So it should be capitalized only at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Guardian Style Guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/a):

> **abbreviations and acronyms**
>
> Use all capitals if an abbreviation is pronounced as the individual letters: BBC, VAT, etc; if it is an acronym (pronounced as a word) spell out with initial capital, eg Nasa, Nato, unless it can be considered to have entered the language as an everyday word, such as awol, laser and, more recently, asbo, pin number and sim card. Note that pdf and plc are lowercase.

So it's "Sonar", since it's an acronym -- or maybe "sonar" if you believe it has become an everyday word.

But the Guardian Style Guide is just one guide. Other publishers may have different guidelines.

Comment: The BBC is and VAT are not abbrev. but acronyms.

Comment: *VAT* is normally pronounced "vee ay tee", so it is not an acronym. In any case that's a direct quote from a reputable style guide. *Sonar* is an acronym, like *Nasa* and *Nato*, but could be considered an everyday word like *laser*

Comment: All acronyms are abbreviations.  In my 'lect, BBC and VAT are abbreviations but not acronyms, since they're pronounced letter-by-letter.  A person who said VAT like "vat" would consider it an acronym (and also an abbreviation). So I disagree with @Pureferret pretty much completely.

Comment: @Pureferret: VAT is usually an initialisation; the BBC is always an initialisation, and not an acronym. Look up the definition of 'acronym'.

Comment: @Marcin "A word formed from the initial letters of other words" In the case of BBC the initial letters are **B** ritish **B** roadcasting **C** ompany. Compared with abbreviation: "A shortened form of a word or phrase" If it was Brit. Broad. Comp. I'd say it was an abbreviation. I see the two as mutually exclusive, but I admit I might be wrong.

Comment: @Pureferret: I don't know how you pronounce "BBC", but I've never met anyone who manages to pronounce it as anything other than a sequence of letters.

Comment: @Charles I don't think grammar should be determined by someone's pronunciation, because then the topic becomes subjective. FWIW I've heard the BBC pronounced as *Beeb* and I personally pronounce VAT as *vat*

Comment: @Marcin BBC pronounced *Beeb*. Also, personally "BBC and VAT are abbreviations but not acronyms, *since they're pronounced letter-by-letter*" sounds counter-intuitive to my native-english mind.

Comment: @pureferret It's pedant territory. The dictionary definition of *acronym* is an initialisation that is pronounced as a word. "Beeb" would therefore only be an acronym if the initialisation was B.E.E.B. -- however lots and lots of people use *acronym* for initialisations that are pronounced letter by letter, such as *TLA* . It's a bit like *disinterested*. Do you just use it "correctly", or point out "by the way, I mean impartial, not uninterested"?

Comment: @Pureferret: "Beeb" is not a pronunciation of "BBC", but a nickname.

Comment: @slim: You may note that pureferret started this flight of pedantry. If we're going to suffer pedantry, it should at least be correct.

Comment: @Marcin the OED defines *both* my interpretation and yours as definitions of [acronym](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844?rskey=atayV9&result=1#eid). I'm not sure what to think of that. Also the OED definition of [abbreviation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180?redirectedFrom=abbreviation#eid) makes not link between the two.

Comment: @pureferret again it's the same story as *disinterested*. OED includes the "correct" definition, and the "incorrect" definition, since the "incorrect" definition is now too widely used to be wrong.

Comment: @slim But the OED gives no indication that one definition is more or less correct than the other. All it does is state that the 'incorrect' usage of the word pre-dates the correct usage of the word.

Comment: The OED does not claim to be an authority on *approved* word meanings, only on *attested* word meanings. The OED gives a "correct" definition of a word only in the sense that the definition given is what is generally understood by English speakers to be the meaning of the word.